# Grails produce seo friendly URLS

Tags: grails, seo

I'm very new to grails and I have some questions about creating views with SEO friendly URLs.

Lets say I have a page I'd like to call used-products or https://www.sampledomain.com/used-products, how would I go about creating a view and have it resolve for used-products?

Another example would be something like /cell-phones/droid-razor-l1956

I'm not familiar enough with model view controllers to know how to structure my controllers / views to produce URLs like this.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me to understand how to achieve this goal.

Comment: Can you try using below mapping
`static mappings = {
  "/product/$type/$name"(controller: "product", action:"show")
}`
in this you can use url like "/product/cell-phones/droid-razor-l1956" which will go to product controller show action with type params as cell-phones and name params as droid-razor-l1956.

Comment: @AnantKolvankar Thanks, I'm assuming if I didn't want /product in the url, I could just remove it from the static mappings?

Comment: So you should use "/$type/$name" in url mappings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**/used-products page**

Create a ProductController with an action like this:

```
def usedProducts = {
   [productList:Product.findAllByUsed(true)]
}
```

Then in UrlMappings, you setup your URL to point to this action:

```
  "/used-products" {
      controller = "product"
      action = "usedProducts"
    }
```

**product detail page**

Follow this excellent tutorial:
http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/12/grails/tutorial-on-how-to-create-grails-seo-friendly-url

Comment: how should I name the view?

Comment: For used-products, name the view usedProducts.gsp

Comment: Thanks Mike, this is exactly what I was looking for. I think from here I'll be able to figure out how to make things more dynamic.

Comment: Just remember that for the individual product pages, you'll want to include the ID somewhere in the URL, just as it's done here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: your example has a compiling error, please remove the comma after "product".